# How to set ContentDistribution password?

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdistribution

I kindly ask for help with setting ContentDistribution password on a published document link. In the Controller I have:

```
        ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
        conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; 
        conVer.PathOnClient = ‘xxx.xls';
        conVer.Title = ‘xxx’;
        conVer.VersionData = excelData;  // taken from VF page which produces XLS document
        insert conVer;

        ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
        cd.name = conVer.Title;
        cd.ContentVersionId = conVer.Id;
        cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = true;
        cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = true;
        cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
        cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
        // cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired = true; // not sure if required?
     // cd.Password = '123';  // not possible, read only <- maybe set the password here somehow?
```

Then in the ContentDistributionTrigger:

```
public override void afterInsert() {

        List<ContentDistribution> afterInsertList = Trigger.New;

        ContentDistribution cd =
            [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl, ContentVersion.ContentDocument.FileType, ContentDocumentId,ContentDownloadUrl
            FROM ContentDistribution
            WHERE Id = :afterInsertList.get(0).Id];

        System.debug(cd.DistributionPublicUrl); // works perfect, but how to protect it with a password?
        System.debug(cd.ContentDownloadUrl);  // works perfect, but how to protect it with a password?
        System.debug('password: '+cd.Password); // empty :-(
}
```

I don’t mind which way the password should be set, either I pass it to the controller, or it can be auto generated, just can’t find a way in the documentation on how to do it (in Apex).

Answer (score 1):

As I could check, the **password** field is not writeable. Hence you cannot set it while creating ContentDistribution or update it later.

**Type**

- string

**Properties**

- Group, Nillable, Sort

**Description**

- A password that allows access to a shared document.

**PreferencesPasswordRequired**:- This field will tell you before sharing you need to set a password or not.

This example will make you more clear:-

> The VP of Marketing wants file authors to specify whether their files
>   can be shared with external people using content delivery. He also
>   wants some files to have a password. You can add a custom field
>   DeliveryPolicy on the ContentVersion object. Make the custom field a
>   picklist with the values, Allowed, Blocked, and Password required. Add
>   the field to the ContentVersion layout so that the user can set the
>   delivery policy per file. Then, add an insert trigger for the
>   ContentDistribution object to enforce the rules based on the delivery
>   policy set in the file.

This trigger for the ContentDistribution object enforces the delivery policy rules for each file:

```
trigger deliveryPolicy on ContentDistribution (before insert) {
    for (ContentDistribution cd : trigger.new) {
        String versionId = DeliveryPolicyHelper.getContentVersionId(cd);
        ContentVersion version = [select DeliveryPolicy__c from ContentVersion where Id = :versionId];
        String policy = version.DeliveryPolicy__c;
        if (policy.equals('Blocked')) {
            cd.addError('This file is not allowed to be delivered.');
        } else if (policy.equals('Password required')){
            if (!DeliveryPolicyHelper.requirePassword(cd)) {
                cd.addError('To deliver this file, set a password.');
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The trigger calls this helper class:-

```
public class DeliveryPolicyHelper {
    public static String getContentVersionId(ContentDistribution cd) {
        if (cd.ContentVersionId != null) {
            return cd.ContentVersionId;
        } else {
            String versionId = [select LatestPublishedVersionId from ContentDocument where Id = :cd.ContentDocumentId].get(0).LatestPublishedVersionId;
            return versionId;
        }
    }

    public static boolean requirePassword(ContentDistribution cd) {
        return cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired;
    }
}
```

Reference:- [ContentDistribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I think I can't use it, or I misunderstand. I forgot to explain the process:

Comment: Yeah please mention it in your Question by updating it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I forgot to explain the process: the user does NOT interact with the default "Content delivery" page. I know that page actually DOES contain "Require Password to Access Content", which DOES generate a password - which is exactly what I want - but PROGRAMMATICALLY :-) In my process the user uses a custom page, filter out data, hit a button which is supposed to 1. generate an Excel, 2. store it to Content, 3. in the trigger send an email with that link to 3rd party, 4. send an SMS with password. I'm stuck on the password. Is that possible, please? Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you stuck with sending SMS? 1. generate an Excel, 2. store it to Content, 3. in the trigger send an email with that link to 3rd party --- Upto here you don't have any problem?

Comment: I'm stuck with generating the password in the ContentDistributionTrigger. Maybe Salesforce does not enable that. I'm thinking about a workaround: jump from my page directly to "Content delivery wizzard - Create content delivery" on that particular content file. The user would just Save it, the system generates the password, the user is done, then the trigger catches the link and password and sends them. Not as cool as automatic password generation but maybe doable. I'll try to figure out a way to jump to Create content delivery wizzard.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, my fault, there is a flag that enforces the system to generate the password immediatelly:

```
        ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
        cd.name = conVer.Title;
        cd.ContentVersionId = conVer.Id;
        cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = true;
        cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = true;
        cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
        cd.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
        cd.PreferencesPasswordRequired = true; // <- this is it
        insert cd;
```

Then in the trigger the password is readable:

ContentDistribution cd = [
                SELECT Id,
                        Name,
                        ContentVersionId,
                        DistributionPublicUrl,
                        ContentDocumentId,
                        ContentDownloadUrl,
                        Password
                FROM ContentDistribution
                WHERE Id = :afterInsertList.get(0).Id
        ];